# NDSolve error: CoefficientArray:... is not a polynomial

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, finite-element-method

I get strange errors (`CoefficientArrays::poly` and `NDSolveValue::femper`) with `NDSolveValue`: it seems it is not parsing the equations in the corrrect way, but I cannot understand what's wrong.

Here is the code:

```
v0=-10^-2;
den[x_, y_, z_] := 10;
p[x_, y_, z_] := 1;
h[x_, y_, z_] := 5;
u0[x_, y_, z_] := 
  Exp[ϕ[x, y, 
     z]] Sqrt@(1 + (v0^2 x^2)/
       Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]^2 Exp[-2 α1[x, y, z]] + (
       v0^2 y^2)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]^2 Exp[-2 β[x, y, z]] + (
       v0^2 z^2)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]^2 Exp[-2 γ[x, y, z]]);
u1[x_, y_, z_] := (v0 x)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
u2[x_, y_, z_] := (v0 y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
u3[x_, y_, z_] := (v0 z)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];

eqn1 = (-Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], z] - 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], z]^2 - 
      Exp[(2*γ[x, y, z])]*
       D[α1[x, y, z], 
        z]*(D[β[x, y, z], z] - D[γ[x, y, z], z]) + 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], z]*
       D[γ[x, y, z], z] + 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], {z, 2}] + 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], {z, 2}] - 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], y]^2 + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], y]*
       D[β[x, y, z], y] - 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], y]*
       D[γ[x, y, z], y] + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], y]*
       D[γ[x, y, z], y] - 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], y]^2 + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], {y, 2}] + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], {y, 2}] + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], x]*
       D[β[x, y, z], x] - 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], x]^2 + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], x]*
       D[γ[x, y, z], x] - 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], x]*
       D[γ[x, y, z], x] - 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], x]^2 + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], {x, 2}] + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], {x, 2}])/
    Exp[2*ϕ[x, y, z]] == (den[x, y, z] h[x, y, z] - 
       p[x, y, z]) u0[x, y, z]^2 - p[x, y, z] Exp[2 ϕ[x, y, z]];

eqn2 = (Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], z]^2 - 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*
       D[β[x, y, z], 
        z]*(D[γ[x, y, z], z] - D[ϕ[x, y, z], z]) - 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], z]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], z] + 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[ϕ[x, y, z], z]^2 - 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], {z, 2}] - 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[ϕ[x, y, z], {z, 2}] - 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], y]*
       D[γ[x, y, z], y] + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], y]^2 - 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], y]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], y] + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], y]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], y] + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[ϕ[x, y, z], y]^2 - 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], {y, 2}] - 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[ϕ[x, y, z], {y, 2}] + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], x]*
       D[γ[x, y, z], x] + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], x]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], x] + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], x]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], x])/
    Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]] == (den[x, y, z] h[x, y, z] - 
       p[x, y, z]) u1[x, y, z]^2 + 
    p[x, y, z] Exp[2 α1[x, y, z]];


eqn3 = (Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], z]^2 - 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*
       D[α1[x, y, z], 
        z]*(D[γ[x, y, z], z] - D[ϕ[x, y, z], z]) - 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], z]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], z] + 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[ϕ[x, y, z], z]^2 - 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], {z, 2}] - 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[ϕ[x, y, z], {z, 2}] + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], y]*
       D[γ[x, y, z], y] + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], y]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], y] + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], y]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], y] - 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], x]*
       D[γ[x, y, z], x] + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], x]^2 - 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], x]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], x] + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], x]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], x] + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[ϕ[x, y, z], x]^2 - 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[γ[x, y, z], {x, 2}] - 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[ϕ[x, y, z], {x, 2}])/
    Exp[2*β[x, y, z]] == (den[x, y, z] h[x, y, z] - 
       p[x, y, z]) u2[x, y, z]^2 + p[x, y, z] Exp[2 β[x, y, z]];

eqn4 = (Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], z]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], z] + 
      Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]]*
       D[α1[x, y, z], 
        z]*(D[β[x, y, z], z] + D[ϕ[x, y, z], z]) + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], y]^2 - 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], y]*
       D[β[x, y, z], y] + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], y]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], y] - 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], y]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], y] + 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[ϕ[x, y, z], y]^2 - 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], {y, 2}] - 
      Exp[2*β[x, y, z]]*D[ϕ[x, y, z], {y, 2}] - 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], x]*
       D[β[x, y, z], x] + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], x]^2 - 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[α1[x, y, z], x]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], x] + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], x]*
       D[ϕ[x, y, z], x] + 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[ϕ[x, y, z], x]^2 - 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[β[x, y, z], {x, 2}] - 
      Exp[2*α1[x, y, z]]*D[ϕ[x, y, z], {x, 2}])/
    Exp[2*γ[x, y, z]] == (den[x, y, z] h[x, y, z] - 
       p[x, y, z]) u3[x, y, z]^2 + 
    p[x, y, z] Exp[2 γ[x, y, z]];
```

Here the `NDSolveValue` step:

```
NDSolveValue[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4, 
  DirichletCondition[ϕ[x, y, z] == 0, True], 
  DirichletCondition[α1[x, y, z] == 0, True], 
  DirichletCondition[β[x, y, z] == 0, True], 
  DirichletCondition[γ[x, y, z] == 0, 
   True]}, {ϕ, α1, β, γ}, {x, -25, 
  25}, {y, -25, 25}, {z, -25, 25}]
```

And here is the error:

[image]

I am sorry for the long code, but I couldn't find a MWE.

Comment: If I evaluate your code on a fresh kernel (V12.3 Windows), I get – after a couple of minutes – a [different error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWZd2.png).

Comment: @Domen I use version 11.3 for Linux

Comment: Your system looks nonlinear. FEM was enhance to deal with nonlinear systems in V12.0, I think. It'd be nice to add the message names so that others can search for the error names to find answers that might help them. I'm getting the same as @Domen in V13, Mac. The kernel did have a "virtual memory size" of over 400GB, though, and "real memory size" of 9GB.

Comment: @MichaelE2 the error names are `CoefficientArrays::poly` and `NDSolveValue::femper`. But would it be possible to solve the system with another method?

Comment: I think `"MethodOfLines"` is the only other in `NDSolve`, but you'd have to reformulate the BCs somewhat, I think. You have to have a variable for the time integration. Others have implemented FDM on this site; you can search for "FDM". I don't do a lot of work with PDEs, so my experience is not extensive.

Comment: @mattiav27 What type of PDEs do you try to solve? Could you give a reference link to this system?

Answer (score 3):

The message you see is because the version of Mathematica that you use does not have the nonlinear finite element solver implemented.  When I run your system in Version 13.0 with a coarser then default mesh:

```
mesh = NDSolve`FEM`ToElementMesh[Cuboid[-25*{1, 1, 1}, 25*{1, 1, 1}], 
  "MaxCellMeasure" -> 50]

NDSolveValue[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4, 
  DirichletCondition[\[Phi][x, y, z] == 0, True], 
  DirichletCondition[\[Alpha]1[x, y, z] == 0, True], 
  DirichletCondition[\[Beta][x, y, z] == 0, True], 
  DirichletCondition[\[Gamma][x, y, z] == 0, 
   True]}, {\[Phi], \[Alpha]1, \[Beta], \[Gamma]}, {x, y, 
   z} \[Element] mesh]
```

[image]

Which means that the solver could not find a solution. That can have various causes. The PDE is not correct, a solution does not exists, the initial seeding of 0 is not good, the solver can not find a solution.... I'd first double check that the PDE is what you want it to be.